# getting error call to undefined function webform_component_edit_form_validate in ctools popup drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform, drupal-ctools

I am using webform module for creating form. I required not to customize webform_component_edit_form. so
I have alter webform_component_edit_form. **In this form alter i add select element with #ajax property. This is working fine when i open this in url. But when i open this form in ctools i am getting error**

```
Call to undefined function webform_component_edit_form_validate() in ../includes/form.inc
```

webform_component_edit_form_validate i written in webform/incluedes/webform.components.inc

any one can suggest me where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It exists in webform/includes/webform.components.inc, so maybe it is not getting included since you are integrating it with a form alter.

Try adding this to your form alter, above the form item you are modifying.

```
require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'webform') . '/includes/webform.components.inc';
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', '/includes/webform.components');
```

in above of my module.
now its working fine.